# IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Key tried: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey'

Tags: c#, validation, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, access-token

I am trying to validate a token from Azure. I used Adal.js to get the token.
When I try to validate the token I always get the same error message every time:

> IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Key tried: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey'.
>   token: '{"typ":"JWT",...

The token omitted from the message looks like what I can see on the client, and the information from the following 3 urls seems to be added into the data structures correctly, i.e. where I can see fields populated it is what I expect from looking at the links below and my token on the client.

https://login.windows.net/{id}.onmicrosoft.com/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{id}.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys

But whenever I reach the final line `ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(...` I always get the same error.

Any ideas one how to make the token validate?

```
        // Get the jwt bearer token from the authorization header
        string jwtToken = null;
        AuthenticationHeaderValue authHeader = request.Headers.Authorization;
        if (authHeader != null)
        {
            jwtToken = authHeader.Parameter;
        }

        string issuer;
        List<SecurityToken> signingTokens;

        // The issuer and signingTokens are cached for 24 hours. They are updated if any of the conditions in the if condition is true.            
        if (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(_stsMetadataRetrievalTime).TotalHours > 24 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_issuer) || _signingTokens == null)
        {
            // Get tenant information that's used to validate incoming jwt tokens
            string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = string.Format("{0}/.well-known/openid-configuration", authority);
            ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint);
            OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync();
            _issuer = config.Issuer;
            _signingTokens = config.SigningTokens.ToList();

            _stsMetadataRetrievalTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

        issuer = _issuer;
        signingTokens = _signingTokens;

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudience = audience,
            ValidIssuer = issuer,
            IssuerSigningTokens = signingTokens,
            CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None
        };

        try {
            // Validate token.
            SecurityToken validatedToken = new JwtSecurityToken();
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwtToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
        }
```

**Update**
Just incase there's something I'm missing when initializing the client and server.

Adal.js init options are:

```
    var endpoints = {
        "https://graph.windows.net": "https://graph.windows.net"
    };
    var configOptions = {
        tenant: "<ad>.onmicrosoft.com", // Optional by default, it sends common
        clientId: "<app ID from azure portal>",
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
        endpoints: endpoints,
    }
    window.authContext = new AuthenticationContext(configOptions);
```

Server init options are:

```
    static string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
    static string tenant = "<ad>.onmicrosoft.com";
    static string audience = "<app ID from azure portal>";
    string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

    static string scopeClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope";
```

Comment: When you [look](https://shawntabrizi.com/jwt) at the token, does the `kid` in the header match any of the `kid`s listed at https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys?

Comment: Yes, they match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What scenario are you trying to implement? The token you have is for AAD Graph API, you don't need to validate it. When performing api calls with that token, microsoft graph server side will validate the access token.

In addition, in your server side init options, you set the audience to app ID from azure portal, which means that when validating the access token, the audience of access token should match app ID from azure portal, but audience of access token is `https://graph.windows.net` since you are acquiring token for Azure AD Graph api.

If the access token is for your own api, you need to validate the access token in your api, you could use OWIN middleware to process the token:

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],

                });
```

or manually validating the JWT token like [this code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation) .

Comment: I am trying to use the token for my own api. Unfortunately my api is not mvc and there seems to be little support for restful apis... 
So far I have made several of the MVC examples for Azure AD work, but have had zero luck when trying to use the calls in my own api

Comment: You could register another app in azure ad to protect your own api , in your client app , acquire token to access your api app ,then in your api , manually validate the access token(audience should be your api app url)  as shown by above code sample .